# DataTable loses connection for large tables on Shiny-Server, but not with local RunApp

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I'm having an issue with large tables in R Shiny DataTable when running on Shiny-Server. After rendering, the page flashes "attempting to reconnect" and then eventually times out and loses the connection. The behaviour occurs when published on Shiny-Server but not when launched locally with `shiny::runApp()`.

A test of 500,000 records with just 3 columns results produces the issues. With small tables, it works fine.

I isolated the issue to the `DT::` package. If I use `shiny::` for `dataTableOutput` and `renderDataTable`, it works fine. But that misses out on all the useful features provided by DT. When the issue is occurring the filtering mechanisms of DataTable are still working and processing on the Server, but other shiny functions will not work.

The code below can reproduce the error:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(num = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0), times=50000),
                 letters = rep(letters[1:10], times=50000),
                 colA = rep(c("apple","orange","pear","grape","onion"), times=100000))

ui <- navbarPage("DataTable test", id="nav",

                 tabPanel("Define Subset", 
                          # Present Datatable
                          fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("mdu_subset_table"), style = "font-size: 85%; width: 100%")
                 ),
                 tags$head(
                   includeCSS("styles.css")
                 )

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # session$allowReconnect(TRUE)

  output$mdu_subset_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    {df}
    , filter="top"
    , options = list(sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip',
                    lengthMenu = c(100,1000)
                    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The R version on the Shiny Server is: R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"

The libraries installed locally and on the shiny server are the same.

No errors appear in the R console log on the shiny server:

```
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43761
~                                                                    
~                            
~
~
~
```

Comment: Without knowing a lot more, my first thought is to use *server-side* processing on the table. Read [here](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html), it can be as simple as adding `server = TRUE` to your render statement. However, because this would suggest network latency or related, this may or may not actually resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @KevinArseneau. Server-side processing is enabled by default and is being used in this example. Attempting to use client-side processing will result in a straightforward error message about the table being too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this issue. The issue was a config for the web-server. The amount of data being requested from datatable on the client side was greater than a setting allowed.

In this case the server shiny was running on used NGINX web server. The parameter that needed to be changed was client_max_body_size, which we bumped up to 20M.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Answer (score 1):

The `output$mdu_subset_table` is incomplete in your question, there is no call to `DT::datatable`.

Replacing that block with the code below works for me.

```
output$mdu_subset_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

  DT::datatable(
    df,
    filter = "top",
    options = list(
      dom = "lrtip",
      lengthMenu = c(100, 1000)
    )
  )

}, server = TRUE)
```

> **N.B.** In your question you include `sDom` within the options list. I've not seen that used elsewhere and have replaced with a standard `dom` entry.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I tried your amendment but it still fails when running on shiny-server. It works fine with runApp(). sDom is a deprecated argument name from DataTable - same thing as dom.

Comment: Hi @AlasdairDouglas, I'm using similar code in a production shiny-server environment with 1M+ rows and many more columns that your example dataset without issue. I would suggest the DT package is not where your problem lies.

Comment: That helps Kevin, thanks. It sounds like there may be a config issue with the  shiny-server and I will need to experiment there.